# Laravel - How to change column type (smallInteger => string)

Tags: laravel

The documentation doesn't say anything about changing data type with migrations.

I have this column in my DB table

```
$table->smallInteger('driverslicensetype')->nullable();
```

and I am saving four-digit numbers, but when the number begins with 0 (a zero) for example 0230 it will be saved as 230 in DB. And that is wrong.

Now i want to change this column data type from smallInteger to varchar.

How can i do this through migrations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the schema changing feature, you need Doctrine DBAL:

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

Now you can use `change()`:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('foo', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('driverlicensetype', 4)->nullable()->change();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('foo', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->smallInteger('driverlicensetype')->nullable()->change();
    });
}
```

If you prefer the raw approach (or if your SQL is more restrictive, like when `driverlicensetype` is a foreign key), use `DB::statement`:

```
public function up()
{
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE foo ...');
}
// ...
```

Comment: I got this error: `[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]                                                                      
  Unknown database type enum requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySQL57Platform may not support it.`

Comment: @lewis4u Please ask this as a new question with the relevant code.